# Mixing Java and JSP code/ Unable to print String to Javascript console some Java information

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat7

So, I'm learning a little bit of JSP and Java and I was trying to test something, after fighting with the code a little bit I realized that this is possible within the  tag:

```
<body>
    <tr> I'm working</tr>
    <tr> 
    <%
    int printInt = 0;

    if (true) {
        printInt = 123;
    } else {
        printInt = 456;
    }    
    out.print(printInt );
    %>
    </tr>
</body>
```

And if I changed the `(true)` to `(false)` the value would change when I reload the page.

Now here's the thing, I tried to make it more complex by using the example from the Java pages from Oracle, but using String instead of char.

```
    int testscore = 76;
    String grade = "";

    if (testscore >= 90) {
        grade = "A";
    } else if (testscore >= 80) {
        grade = "B";
    } else if (testscore >= 70) {
        grade = "C";
    } else if (testscore >= 60) {
        grade = "D";
    } else {
        grade = "F";
    }
    out.print("Grade = " + grade);
```

But it wouldn't work. The page wouldn't even load. I started deleting code until I realized that I couldn't even declare a String! Any kind of reference to the type String would crash the page!

I also realized that if I tried to `out.print("I'm working")` wouldn't work either.

Am I supposed to import the String class? Even if it's a JSP page?

I tried adding `<%@page import="java.lang"%>` but this also broke the page.

Anyways, I'm running Tomcat 7 too, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Can you post complete jsp ?

Comment: try import static java.lang.System.out;

Comment: A friend just told me to try <%@page import="java.lang.*"%> and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, <%@page import="java.lang.*"%> seemed to make everything work.